# Output to terminal and output to file getting different result

Tags: python

I think this is a encoding issue but basically i have a python script opening a file and grabbing some lines to then output to a new file.
When i output the results to the terminal they are as i expect but when i do it to a file it is putting as some encoded text / bytes?

```
with open("output_changed2.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for i in range(1, len(content)+1):
        
        if i % 2 == 0: 
            print(content[i].strip() +'|'+ content[i+2].strip())`
```

Sample string from output_changed2

|2009|2|John Frizzell|Carrie's Suspicion

0|Carrie's Suspicion|John Frizzell|0|Defloration Of A Carrier Pigeon And The Lovely Meal It Was Afterwards|Suspicion Breeds Confidence||

In terminal this prints as |2009|2|John Frizzell|Carrie's Suspicion
0|Carrie's Suspicion|John Frizzell|0|Defloration Of A Carrier Pigeon And The Lovely Meal It Was Afterwards|Suspicion Breeds Confidence||

In output file by either writing with another opened file or simply outputting like myscript >> myfile.txt is giving triangle/question mark symbols. I have tried opening a temp file and writing to it but it has the same result.

Im trying to get it as it is in my terminal so i can import the data into a excel sheet

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it helps a lot. Also apply care to the formatting of your question, specially whant it deals with bad output formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not show how you write to the file. I assume you do something like :

```py
with open("output_changed2.txt") as f, open("output.txt", "wt") as output_file:
    # I added this part              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    content = f.readlines()
    for i in range(1, len(content) -2):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(content[i].strip() + '|' + content[i + 2].strip())
            output_file.write(content[i].strip() + '|' + content[i + 2].strip())
            # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ writing to the file
```

I created this content for `output_changed2.txt` because you did not supply yours :

```
something something something
something something something
|2009|2|John Frizzell|Carrie's Suspicion
something something something
0|Carrie's Suspicion|John Frizzell|0|Defloration Of A Carrier Pigeon And The Lovely Meal It Was Afterwards|Suspicion Breeds Confidence||
something something something
something something something
```

It produces the following output on stdout :

```
|2009|2|John Frizzell|Carrie's Suspicion|0|Carrie's Suspicion|John Frizzell|0|Defloration Of A Carrier Pigeon And The Lovely Meal It Was Afterwards|Suspicion Breeds Confidence||
0|Carrie's Suspicion|John Frizzell|0|Defloration Of A Carrier Pigeon And The Lovely Meal It Was Afterwards|Suspicion Breeds Confidence|||something something something
```

And the same thing but on only one line in the `output.txt` file :

```
|2009|2|John Frizzell|Carrie's Suspicion|0|Carrie's Suspicion|John Frizzell|0|Defloration Of A Carrier Pigeon And The Lovely Meal It Was Afterwards|Suspicion Breeds Confidence||0|Carrie's Suspicion|John Frizzell|0|Defloration Of A Carrier Pigeon And The Lovely Meal It Was Afterwards|Suspicion Breeds Confidence|||something something something
```

It is because [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) has a default parameter `end='\n'` so it automatically adds a newline after each call unless told otherwise. But [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) just write exactly what it is given.

I think the difference you observe come from there.

Also, your loop will `IndexError: list index out of range` because inside you access `content[i + 2]` but you iterate `for i in range(1, len(content)+1)` so at one point your `i` will become `len(content)` and thus `i+2` be out of bounds.